# individual text overlay for each image

Tags: html, css, overlay

so i have 12 images in columns. a couple of the images, when clicked, lead to another page. i want some of the images, when clicked, to open up a text box and dim the background (overlay). however, i want each image to open up a text box that says it's own thing. i've read that this can be done with just css but i'm not sure how to go about this since i want each image to have it's own textbox.

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale" src="img6.jpg" width="220px"height="220px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <a href="christmas_homepage.html"><img class="grayscale" src="img1.png" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale" src="uiuc.png" width="220px"height="220px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <a href="cupcakes.html"><img class="grayscale"src="img4.png" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                     <img class="grayscale"src="swe.png" width="220px"height="220px"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale" src="fashion2.png" width="220px"height="220px">
                    <!-- the runway  needs to be clickable-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale" src="india.png" width="220px"height="220px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale"src="nielsen.png" width="220px"height="220px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class ="boxed">
                    <img class="grayscale" src="city.png" width="220px"height="220px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in this case, i'd like img6 and img1 to have these effects if possible.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

off course, overlay is a work of css and basically a work of z-index. Since, you want each image, redirect to its own page, So, within you anchor tag `<a></a>`, use a `<div id="overlay"><img src="#"></div>` and design your div with hover effect using css. Also, if you want to appear some texts on mouse enter, you must have to use Javascript.